# When I was trying to run IPEX on DevCloud it is showing "Illegal instruction"

Tags: python, pytorch, intel-pytorch

I was trying image classification using IPEX on DevCloud  but it is showing "Illegal instruction" for me.

```html
qsub -I -l nodes=1:gpu:ppn=2 -d .
python3 inf.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
qsub -I -l nodes=1:gpu:ppn=2 -d .
```

This command is used to assign one full GPU node.
IPEX don't support gpu as mentioned here:
https://github.com/intel/intel-extension-for-pytorch/issues/149#issuecomment-812348623

This could be the reason for that error.

Try using below commands:

```
qsub -I
python3 inf.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently, Intel® Extension for PyTorch* extends PyTorch with up-to-date features and optimizations on Intel GPU for an extra performance boost on Intel Graphics cards.
Please check out the link, https://intel.github.io/intel-extension-for-pytorch/xpu/latest/index.html.